# Effect of output inductor DCR on switching power supply

Tags: power-electronics, component-selection, passive-components

I'm not an EE but I'm attempting to gain hobby levels of the skill.  So I'm building a DC/DC power supply as an exercise.  I built a PCB design for a TI chip (TPS560200) with associated passives based on the information in the datasheet.  After sending the PCB off to fab I decided to throw the chip into WEBENCH and most parameters are on target except for the tool specifies an output inductor with 33mOhm DCR as if that's important.

My question is, is it?  I believe I understand the place of the inductor in the circuit but I can't reason about the effect of DCR.  Maybe a different DCR might effect the balance of the voltage divider but only for the portions of the signal which appear as DC to the inductor?  Is it something else?  Or is WEBENCH just specifying DCR blindly here?

Comment: 330**Mega**Ohm? You sure?

Comment: The main effect of the DCR is on efficiency and temperature rise of the inductor.  If the DCR is too high your inductor might get too hot, exceeding the max operating temperature of the part.  There are other effects too, but those are the first ones to worry about.  The loop will take care of the output impedance, so Zout of the supply isn't a consideration.

Comment: @brhans I was mistaken.  33mOhm DCR

Comment: @JohnD okay so then as long as my inductor is rated for my power I might suffer some efficiency going with a different DCR but it should be fine?

Comment: @foreverska In general, yes.  However there are AC and core losses in an inductor too, so your temperature rise will be higher than just the I^2R DC losses in the winding.  Best to be conservative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inductor DC resistance affects overall efficiency. If you choose a high DCR then the inductor will heat up more, possibly to the point of losing its own inductance. The inductor datasheet will have a thermal derating for this.

330 mOhm (0.330 Ohm) is marginal for a 500mA regulator, having .083W loss. You could make better choices to further improve efficiency; WebBench lets you experiment with that.

Comment: There is a bit of mysticism surrounding what WeBench does and doesn't allow me to do being young with power circuits.  So I tend to avoid trying to tune things but I did manage to tune the maximum rated current and watch the inverse relationship with DCR so thanks for that point.

Comment: A tradeoff you can make is to use a smaller value inductor - say, 4.7uH - which will give larger ripple but will also have lower DCR. You can compensate for that by increasing the output capacitance. As long as your ripple current is less than 30% at max load it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The main effect of DCR is \$I^2R\$ losses in the inductor, which reduce efficiency and heat up the inductor.  As long as you don't mind an inefficient supply, and as long as your inductor is big enough that it doesn't overheat, you'll be fine.

If you *did* put an itty bitty inductor in there with a significantly higher resistance, it'll just melt off the board, and then it'll stop wasting power!